# list of games to open radar match in iframe on for drop-down controls

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, event-handling, d3.js

In general my page is slow and has several points in the code that I believe can be improved, even in relation to the structure used. Anyway, the biggest problem is:

The page I'm creating is very simple. The problem is that I created the entire first section - i.e. `<div class="column ...">` but then I had to use the famous `Ctrl + C` and `Ctrl + V` to create the other `<div class="column ...">` because I don't know how to group scripts - this is making page load slower.

The `<select>` elements for example is created from script's. They told me that there is a way to make the 4 scripts (one in each `<div class="column ...">`) become one using looping, decreasing the loading the page, but I don't know how to make this improvement.

I was also told about the risk of using so many equal headers, as I use the `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>` four times but how I need it for the 4 scripts, I don't know how I could place it only once unless I merge the 4 scripts into one.

***References for code citations:***

Scripts to `<select>` creation:

```
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-2">
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-3">
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-4">
```

Example of the `.csv` file (`"Lista_de_Jogos.csv"`) that is used to create dropdown selection boxes:

```
label,value
,
Oriente Petrolero v Aurora,http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betting/e/21185256/Oriente+Petrolero+v+Aurora.html
Pereira v Alianza Petrolera,http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betting/e/21150687/Pereira+v+Alianza+Petrolera.html
Tijuana (Women) v Toluca (Women),http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betting/e/21193317/Tijuana+%28Women%29+v+Toluca+%28Women%29.html
Cruz Azul v Mazatlan,http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betting/e/21090457/Cruz+Azul+v+Mazatlan.html
```

Screenshot to drop down box created by `<script>`:

[image: screenshot of drop-down boxes]

***There are other improvements that can be made to shorten the code and speed up the page, but my knowledge is still very small and I need help both to learn and produce results. Thank you in advance for your attention and help!***

My Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .column {
            text-align:center;
            float: left;
            width: 355;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            }
            .button {
            background-color: #33ccff;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            body {
            overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script id="auto-update-images">
            let interval_images
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                interval_images = setInterval(refresh_images, 500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
            })
            
            function refresh_images() {
                if (!document.images) return;
                document.images['grafico-betfair-1'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-1').value;
                document.images['grafico-betfair-2'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-2').value;
                document.images['grafico-betfair-3'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-3').value;
                document.images['grafico-betfair-4'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-4').value;
            }
        </script>
        <script id="auto-update-csv">
            let interval_csv
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                interval_csv = setInterval(refresh_csv, 60000); // refresh every 60 secs
            })
            
            function refresh_csv() {
                d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_1(data)});
                d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_2(data)});
                d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_3(data)});
                d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_4(data)});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-1">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-1">
                        <button class="button" id="botao-do-radar-1" onclick="funcao_radar_1()">Radar 1</button>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-1" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <iframe id="iframe-do-radar-1" width="100%" height="282" frameBorder="0" src="">
                </iframe>
                <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
                    var select_1 = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1")
                    .append("select")
                    .attr("id","select-box-1")
                    .style("width","100%");
                    
                    function caixa_suspensa_1(data) {
                    select_1
                        .on("change", function(d) {
                        var value_1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                        document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-1').value = value_1;
                        document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-1').click();
                        });
                    let update_1 = select_1.selectAll("option")
                        .data(data);
                    update_1.exit().remove();
                    update_1.enter().append("option").merge(update_1)
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
                    }
                    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_1(data)});
                </script>
                <script id="script-para-ativar-iframe-1">
                    function funcao_radar_1() {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('formulario-radar-1'), url = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-1'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-do-radar-1');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            try {
                                let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-1").value;
                                let valor_da_barra_de_texto_1 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                valor_da_barra_de_texto_1 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_1.split("/")[0];
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_1;
                            } catch (e) {
                                        try {
                                            let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-1").value;
                                            let valor_da_barra_de_texto_1 = link.split("betting/e/")[1];
                                            valor_da_barra_de_texto_1 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_1.split("/")[0];
                                                event.preventDefault();
                                                the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_1;
                                        } catch (e) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                    the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                        }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                </script>
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-grafico-1">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-grafico-1" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="grafico-betfair-1">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-para-limpar-texto-1">
                    <div>
                        <button class="button" style="width: 100%;" id="botao-de-limpar-texto-1" onclick="limpar_texto_1()">Limpar Tudo <br/>1</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script id="script-para-limpar-dados-1">
                    function limpar_texto_1() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('formulario-para-limpar-texto-1');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){ 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-1').value="";
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-1').value="";
                            document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-1').click();
                            document.getElementById("select-box-1").selectedIndex = "0";
                        };
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column middle1">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-2">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-2">
                        <button class="button" id="botao-do-radar-2" onclick="funcao_radar_2()">Radar 2</button>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-2" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <iframe id="iframe-do-radar-2" width="100%" height="282" frameBorder="0" src="">
                </iframe>
                <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-2">
                    var select_2 = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-2")
                    .append("select")
                    .attr("id","select-box-2")
                    .style("width","100%");
                    
                    function caixa_suspensa_2(data) {
                    select_2
                        .on("change", function(d) {
                        var value_2 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                        document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-2').value = value_2;
                        document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-2').click();
                        });
                    let update_2 = select_2.selectAll("option")
                        .data(data);
                    update_2.exit().remove();
                    update_2.enter().append("option").merge(update_2)
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
                    }
                    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_2(data)});
                </script>
                <script id="script-para-ativar-iframe-2">
                    function funcao_radar_2() {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('formulario-radar-2'), url = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-do-radar-2');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            try {
                                let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-2").value;
                                let valor_da_barra_de_texto_2 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                valor_da_barra_de_texto_2 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_2.split("/")[0];
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_2;
                            } catch (e) {
                                        try {
                                            let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-2").value;
                                            let valor_da_barra_de_texto_2 = link.split("betting/e/")[1];
                                            valor_da_barra_de_texto_2 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_2.split("/")[0];
                                                event.preventDefault();
                                                the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_2;
                                        } catch (e) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                    the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                        }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                </script>
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-grafico-2">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-grafico-2" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="grafico-betfair-2">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-para-limpar-texto-2">
                    <div>
                        <button class="button" style="width: 100%;" id="botao-de-limpar-texto-2" onclick="limpar_texto_2()">Limpar Tudo <br/>2</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script id="script-para-limpar-dados-2">
                    function limpar_texto_2() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('formulario-para-limpar-texto-2');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){ 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-2').value="";
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-2').value="";
                            document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-2').click();
                            document.getElementById("select-box-2").selectedIndex = "0";
                        };
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column middle2">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-3">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-3">
                        <button class="button" id="botao-do-radar-3" onclick="funcao_radar_3()">Radar 3</button>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-3" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <iframe id="iframe-do-radar-3" width="100%" height="282" frameBorder="0" src="">
                </iframe>
                <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-3">
                    var select_3 = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-3")
                    .append("select")
                    .attr("id","select-box-3")
                    .style("width","100%");
                    
                    function caixa_suspensa_3(data) {
                    select_3
                        .on("change", function(d) {
                        var value_3 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                        document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-3').value = value_3;
                        document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-3').click();
                        });
                    let update_3 = select_3.selectAll("option")
                        .data(data);
                    update_3.exit().remove();
                    update_3.enter().append("option").merge(update_3)
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
                    }
                    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_3(data)});
                </script>
                <script id="script-para-ativar-iframe-3">
                    function funcao_radar_3() {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('formulario-radar-3'), url = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-3'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-do-radar-3');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            try {
                                let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-3").value;
                                let valor_da_barra_de_texto_3 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                valor_da_barra_de_texto_3 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_3.split("/")[0];
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_3;
                            } catch (e) {
                                        try {
                                            let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-3").value;
                                            let valor_da_barra_de_texto_3 = link.split("betting/e/")[1];
                                            valor_da_barra_de_texto_3 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_3.split("/")[0];
                                                event.preventDefault();
                                                the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_3;
                                        } catch (e) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                    the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                        }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                </script>
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-grafico-3">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-grafico-3" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="grafico-betfair-3">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-para-limpar-texto-3">
                    <div>
                        <button class="button" style="width: 100%;" id="botao-de-limpar-texto-3" onclick="limpar_texto_3()">Limpar Tudo <br/>3</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script id="script-para-limpar-dados-3">
                    function limpar_texto_3() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('formulario-para-limpar-texto-3');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){ 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-3').value="";
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-3').value="";
                            document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-3').click();
                            document.getElementById("select-box-3").selectedIndex = "0";
                        };
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column right">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-4">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-4">
                        <button class="button" id="botao-do-radar-4" onclick="funcao_radar_4()">Radar 4</button>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-4" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <iframe id="iframe-do-radar-4" width="100%" height="282" frameBorder="0" src="">
                </iframe>
                <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-4">
                    var select_4 = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-4")
                    .append("select")
                    .attr("id","select-box-4")
                    .style("width","100%");
                    
                    function caixa_suspensa_4(data) {
                    select_4
                        .on("change", function(d) {
                        var value_4 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                        document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-4').value = value_4;
                        document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-4').click();
                        });
                    let update_4 = select_4.selectAll("option")
                        .data(data);
                    update_4.exit().remove();
                    update_4.enter().append("option").merge(update_4)
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
                    }
                    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_4(data)});
                </script>
                <script id="script-para-ativar-iframe-4">
                    function funcao_radar_4() {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('formulario-radar-4'), url = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-4'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-do-radar-4');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            try {
                                let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-4").value;
                                let valor_da_barra_de_texto_4 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                valor_da_barra_de_texto_4 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_4.split("/")[0];
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_4;
                            } catch (e) {
                                        try {
                                            let link = document.getElementById("barra-de-texto-para-radar-4").value;
                                            let valor_da_barra_de_texto_4 = link.split("betting/e/")[1];
                                            valor_da_barra_de_texto_4 = valor_da_barra_de_texto_4.split("/")[0];
                                                event.preventDefault();
                                                the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + valor_da_barra_de_texto_4;
                                        } catch (e) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                    the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                        }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                </script>
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-grafico-4">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-grafico-4" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="grafico-betfair-4">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-para-limpar-texto-4">
                    <div>
                        <button class="button" style="width: 100%;" id="botao-de-limpar-texto-4" onclick="limpar_texto_4()">Limpar Tudo <br/>4</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script id="script-para-limpar-dados-4">
                    function limpar_texto_4() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('formulario-para-limpar-texto-4');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){ 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-4').value="";
                            document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-radar-4').value="";
                            document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-4').click();
                            document.getElementById("select-box-4").selectedIndex = "0";
                        };
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By “_In general my page is slow_” in which ways is it slow? Slow to load all of the HTML, slow in having the JS operate? Slow to modify the code because of how large it is?

Comment: Hi @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ good Morning. The page itself loads quickly, I meant that the script is very long because there is a lot that I used copy and paste, for example, there are 4 columns that are totally the same, scripts that import the same data and do pretty much the same thing, and already me they warned that there is a way to summarize a lot, but I don't know how to proceed, so I believe there are ways to unite a lot that I believe can take away so much repetition, making it too big, ugly and complicated to update any details that I need to update.

Comment: I apologize for my English, it's pretty flawed! Any questions you can ask, I', here to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy-Pasted code

As you disclosed, the code has a lot of code that is copied and pasted. This violates the [***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself* principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/) .

> I was also told about the risk of using so many equal headers, as I use the `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>` four times but how I need it for the 4 scripts, I don't know how I could place it only once unless I merge the 4 scripts into one.

> ```
> <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
> ```

This does not need to appear more than once, since the browser will only load it once. Just have it once and the browser will load it. It could be moved to the `<head>` tag instead of the `<body>`.

And all of the contents of the `<script>` tags - e.g. with id values `auto-update-images`, `auto-update-csv`, `script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1`, etc. can be combined into a single element or moved to an external javascript file.

### Abstracting common functionality

Loops can really help with repeated code - for example - these repeated lines in `refresh_images`:

> ```
> document.images['grafico-betfair-1'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-1').value;
> document.images['grafico-betfair-2'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-2').value;
> document.images['grafico-betfair-3'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-3').value;
> document.images['grafico-betfair-4'].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-4').value;
> ```

Can be simplified with a loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    document.images['grafico-betfair-' + i].src = document.getElementById('barra-de-texto-para-grafico-' + i).value;
 }
```

After considering what that function does it looks like it is constantly looking for changes to the `<input>` elements - like here:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formulario-grafico-2">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-grafico-2" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
</form>
<img src="https://sited...1e839c" name="grafico-betfair-2">
```

Instead of having to constant check those values, a class name could be applied to the `<form>` element - e.g.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="imageSrcInputForm">
```

Then in the Javascript look for those elements:

```
const imageSrcInputForms = document.getElementsByClassName('imageSrcInputForm');
[...imageSrcInputForms].forEach(form => {
    form.querySelector('img').addEventListener('change', event => {
        form.nextElementSibling.src = event.target.value;
    });
}];
```

There may not even really be a need to have a `<form>` just to wrap the `<input>` element.

You may be able to eliminate the redundancy on the repeated functions -e.g. `funcao_radar_1`, `funcao_radar_2`... using loop over elements with class names. And instead of traversing the DOM tree to find elements there could be associations with elements using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

### Simplifying one line functions

The d3 selector lines have lines like this:

> ```
> .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
> .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
> ```

Just as the event listeners for the DOM-content loaded event use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), those lines can be simplified as well:

```
.attr("value", d => d.value)
.text(d => d.label);
```

### CSS- units

The ruleset for `.column` contains `width: 355;` The default unit is pixels - i.e. `px` but it should be declared for clarity. Apparently [~4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45636797/1575353) popular browsers treated this as invalid<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45636797/1575353)</sup> however in FF and Chrome today I see it treated as 355 pixels.

Comment: Hi Sam, Vast content for my learning, thank you very much! If I have any questions regarding the nominations, can I ask you as an additional?